# How to create a gameobject in Unity with c# that spawns in x time and it is inside a Scene

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, time

I want to spawn a GameObject in Unity when the Scene has been active for 9 secconds. I used Time.timeSinceStartup but it starts to count secconds since i start the whole game. Does anybody know which is the script to start counting the time from the start of a scene?

Comment: `timeSinceLevelLoad` but you would be fine doing this in a `start` method..

Comment: The solution by @TheLazyScripter may be much more accurate than `Time.deltaTime` in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are about 100 ways to achieve what you want to do (mainly coroutines) however I am assuming you are just getting started therefore in my opinion the easiest way to do it is this.

Attach this script to an empty gameobject in the scene. (Note: this script destroys itself but not the gameobject. If you want to destroy gameobject, instead of "this" write "gameobejct".)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnDelay : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] GameObject Prefab;
    [SerializeField] float DelayInSeconds;

    float timer;

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer >= DelayInSeconds)
        {
            Instantiate(Prefab);
            Destroy(this);          //Destroys itself to save memory
        }
    }
}
```